# SSRS how to sort date in MM/YY format?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm stuck at this point, I get my data from a stored procedure with the date format as `MM/YY`, but SSRS sorted my date in a wrong way: 01/2019, 02/2019,..., 12/2019;01/2018, 02/2018,...

So I'd like to do to have my data in the right order.

Comment: **Define** *"right order"* .....

Answer (score 1):

Since your date is converted to MM/YYYY format, the data is text and not numerical so it's sorted one character at a time rather than by the value.

If you want to sort by year and then by month, you would need a separate SORT option for each that parses the text into separate month and year values.

```
=RIGHT(Fields!DOB.Value, 4)
```

This gets the 4 characters from the right of the text which is the year in the data.

```
=LEFT(Fields!DOB.Value, 2)
```

LEFT , 2 gets the first two characters of the string - the month in the field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column in the query where you convert the string date to a date data-type and sort on that e.g.

```
select
  convert(date, '01/'+ MyDateStringColumn) MyDateColumn
from MyTable
order by MyDateColumn
```